# Simultaneously creating property and incrementing value

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm new at this, so I apologize if this is a stupid question, and I apologize with prefacing my question with an apology.

I'm trying to count the values in an array and sort them into properties named for each value.

This is the original code I wrote:

```
var reps = {};

function sortReps(series){
  var num;
  for (var i=0; i<series.length; i++) {
    num = series[i];
    reps[num]++;
  }
}

var arr = [1,3,3,5,7,9,9,9];

sortReps(arr);

console.log(reps);
```

Ideally, the console would print {
  1: 1,
  3: 2,
  5: 1,
  7: 1,
  9: 3
}

But instead it prints
{
  1: NaN,
  3: NaN,
  5: NaN,
  7: NaN,
  9: NaN
}

What's weird to me is that if I don't include the "++", the properties never get created at all.

I've determined that the ++ works fine if the property already has a value, as long as it's not undefined. However, I obviously can't set the value to be 0 each time it loops or else it won't work as a counter.

I even tried adding another function to add values to the properties after they've been created:

```
var reps = {};

function createReps(series){
  var num;
  for (var i=0; i<series.length; i++) {
    num = series[i];
    reps[num]++;
  }
}

function sortReps(ser){
  var nume;
  for (var j=0; j<series.length; j++) {
  num = series[j];
  reps[nume]++;
}

var arr = [1,3,3,5,7,9,9,9,42];

createReps(arr);
sortReps(arr);

console.log(reps);
```

But it just comes up with an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of series??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop check if `reps[num]` is defined if not declare it to 0.

```
var reps = {};

function sortReps(series){
  var num;
  for (var i=0; i<series.length; i++) {
    num = series[i];
    if(reps[num] === undefined)reps[num]=0;
    reps[num]++;
  }
}

var arr = [1,3,3,5,7,9,9,9];

sortReps(arr);

console.log(reps); // { 1: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1, 9: 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `||` operator to get a zero if the property is undefined, then add 1 to it and store in the property:

```
reps[num] = (reps[num] || 0) + 1;
```

You get an error in the second code because you are using `series` in `sortReps`, but the parameter is names `ser`, so it's undefined. Also, you create a global variable `num` and use the undefined `nume`, and it' missing a closing bracket. Anyhow, apart from not working, the `sortReps` function does the same as `createReps`, so it wouldn't change anything to have two functions. Adding more ones to a `NaN` still give you `NaN`.

Comment: It worked, thanks! (I'd upvote your answer but I don't have a high enough reputation yet)

Yeah, I just copied the first function to test if that might work, and I forgot to change some of the variables. I thought maybe if the first function set the property names, then the second function would define the values, but I understand now why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `reps[num]++` when the original value for that position is `undefined`. You will get `NaN` (not a number).  You need to do this:

```
reps[num] = (reps[num]||0)+1;
```

It will use an existing value, or 0 when an item is undefined, then add 1 to it.

Comment: Got it. I changed it and it worked. Thanks! (I'd upvote your answer but I don't have a high enough reputation yet)